# Undefined offset Notice in basic PHP script

Tags: php, post, undefined, offset, notice

This is my first question ever in stackoverflow.

So here is my code:

```
    <form method="post" action="#">
    <input type="text" name="tags">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<?php if ($_POST && isset($_POST['tags'])) {
        $tags =  explode(', ', $_POST['tags']);
        for ($i=0; $i <= count($tags); $i++) { 
                echo htmlentities("$i : " . $tags[$i]) . "</br>";
        }
    }
?>
```

The code works and prints everything split by ", " but it gives me a Notice and it makes me go nuts.

**notice**

> Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in C:\xampp\htdocs..\01.PrintTags.php on
>   line 16 3 :

I hope someone who has more experience than me could give me some tips on how to fix that and explain to me why is it happening.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: instead of `$i <= count($tags)` in the for loop, you should give `$i < count($tags)`. This is a classic 'off-by-one` error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is happening because you are starting your loop from 0 and ending the total length of array . either start your loop from `1` or remove the `=` sign from your loop. with your way the loop will run more than 1 step than the values in the array. use this

```
<?php if ($_POST && isset($_POST['tags'])) {
        $tags =  explode(', ', $_POST['tags']);
        for ($i=0; $i < count($tags); $i++) { 
                echo htmlentities("$i : " . $tags[$i]) . "</br>";
        }
    }
?>
```

best way is you can use foreach for this . Like

```
foreach($tags as $key=>$val)
{
echo $val;
}
```